# Query influxdb with special character

Tags: python, influxdb

I am trying to perform. simple get on influxdb using python. The connection works great and I am able to query several values. However, I have one of them which is reported as `homeassistant.autogen.°C`. When I try to query it, I always get

```
influxdb.exceptions.InfluxDBClientError: 400: {"error":"error parsing query: found \u00b0, expected identifier at line 1, char 43"}
```

The code that is use is:

```
client = InfluxDBClient(host='192.168.1.x', port=8086, username='user', password='password')
results = client.query(r'SELECT "value" FROM homeassistant.autogen."°C" WHERE entity_id = sensor.x_temperature')
```

I already tried to escape and pass it through quotes but nothing seems to work.

I cannot change how the value is inserted in influxdb.

Comment: Can you share the whole code/query?

Comment: I just added it

Comment: Try `SELECT "value" FROM "homeassistant"."autogen"."°C" WHERE entity_id = sensor.x_temperature`. OTherwise, please show the db structure

Comment: Tried, now the problem seems to be the `WHERE=`. If I remove the `WHERE` clause, everything works, but when I add it it gives me a 200 message which is fine, with zero data. I can see that the query sent becomes like this: `"GET /query?q=SELECT+value+FROM+homeassistant.autogen.%22%C2%B0C%22+WHERE+entity_id+%3D+sensor.bagno_camere_temperature HTTP/1.1" 200 None`

Comment: You'll need to quote those fields aswell because the `.` could cause issues; `WHERE "entity_id" = "sensor.x_temperature"'` Or `"sensor"."x_temperature"`

Comment: I already tried, but it keeps returning 0 rows.

Comment: looks like package not supporting unicode in queries. i think you need to edit https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-client-python/blob/60438b215603175da7f02ffe910c0fbb7a08732e/influxdb_client/client/query_api.py#L90 this file on your installation. add ,content_type="text/plain; charset=utf-8" after _return_http_data_only=False.
it should look like this:
response = self._query_api.post_query(org=org, query=self._create_query(query, self.default_dialect, params), async_req=False, _preload_content=False, _return_http_data_only=False, content_type="text/plain; charset=utf-8")

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried escaping with a backslash?

```
client = InfluxDBClient(host='192.168.1.x', port=8086, username='user', password='password')
results = client.query(r'SELECT "value" FROM homeassistant.autogen.\°C WHERE entity_id = sensor.x_temperature')
```

or containing the entire field name in double quotes, e.g.:

```
client = InfluxDBClient(host='192.168.1.x', port=8086, username='user', password='password')
results = client.query(r'SELECT "value" FROM "homeassistant.autogen.°C" WHERE entity_id = sensor.x_temperature')
```

https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/write_protocols/line_protocol_reference/